# How to rename a group of files with what looks like a Windows file path in their names

Tags: command-line, rename, batch-rename

I got a bunch of files with the filename messed up. All the file names have the same beginning which appear to be windows file directories. The problem is there are 700+ files and I really don't want go through and manually rename all of them. These are examples of the file names (Note: None of these have file directories):

```
G:some\really\long\file\path\then\the\name1.jpg
G:some\really\long\file\path\then\the\name2.png
G:some\really\long\file\path\then\the\filename.txt
G:some\really\long\file\path\then\the\file_name.mov
...
```

The important take away is that each file has `G:some\really\long\file\path\then\the\` before the file name that I would like.

So I would want the above files to look like:

```
name1.jpg
name2.png
filename.txt
file_name.mov
```

I've tried the `rename` command and was not successful. I am still new with Linux and really am not sure on how to go about it or really what to google. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I just removed everything up to the last backslash with `rename`

```
$ rename -n 's/.*\\//' G*
rename(G:some\really\long\file\path\then\the\file_name.mov, file_name.mov)
rename(G:some\really\long\file\path\then\the\filename.txt, filename.txt)
rename(G:some\really\long\file\path\then\the\name1.jpg, name1.jpg)
rename(G:some\really\long\file\path\then\the\name2.png, name2.png)
```

Remove `-n` after testing to actually rename the files.

#### Notes

- `-n` don't do anything, just print what will be changed
- `s/old/new` replace `old` with `new`
- `.*` any number of any characters
- `\\` The first backslash is to escape the second one.
- Since regex are greedy this expression `.*\\` eats all the preceding backslashes too.
- Since the last two delimiters `//` are empty everything matched in the search part is deleted

Comment: Do I just need the first line, or do I need to do that for every file?

Comment: you just need the first line @kingcobra1986 the others are just the output. `*` matches all files but let me change that to `G*` - done - so now it matches all files starting with `G` in the current directory and will work on them all at once. If they are in multiple directories we can deal with that too in various ways

Comment: That worked. Can you explain what exactly happens in that line?

Comment: @kingcobra1986 sorry, I added notes. Hope it's clear, if not, please feel free to ask for more!

Comment: Ha, I like the idea to use the `.*\\ ` since of the greedy `.*`

Answer (score 10):

You can do this in pure `bash` using [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

`${file##*\\}` (cut-up-to-last-prefix) strips everything from the start of the filename until last `\` seen.

```bsh
for file in *; do
    mv -v "$file" "${file##*\\}";
done
```

The rename results are:

```
‘G:some\\really\\long\\file\\path\\then\\the\\file_name.mov’ -> ‘file_name.mov’
‘G:some\\really\\long\\file\\path\\then\\the\\filename.txt’ -> ‘filename.txt’
‘G:some\\really\\long\\file\\path\\then\\the\\name1.jpg’ -> ‘name1.jpg’
‘G:some\\really\\long\\file\\path\\then\\the\\name2.png’ -> ‘name2.png’
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're looking for **GUI** solutions, there are many bulk renaming applications. I would suggest **Thunar**, which is the default file manager for Xfce. It comes with a handy bulk renaming tool. You can install Thunar by running the following command in Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install thunar
```

You'll probably be able to install from Ubuntu Software too.

### How to use the utility

1. Once you've installed Thunar, launch the **Bulk Rename** utility.
2. Click on the **+** icon and add the files you want to rename.
3. Click on the drop-down box just below the list of selected files and select **Search & Replace**.
4. In the *Search For:* box enter `G:some\really\long\file\path\then\the\` (the part you want to get rid of), leave the *Replace With:* box empty. You should see the preview of the changes in the *New Name* column.
5. To apply the changes click on the **Rename Files** button.

Besides *Search & Replace* this utility supports the following actions:

- Insert Date / Time
- Insert / Overwrite
- Numbering
- Remove Characters
- Uppercase / Lowercase

Comment: isn't there one for nautilus (I think there is!)? Seems rather overkill to suggest installing a new file browser for this purpose.

Comment: @Zanna There is one in v3.22, but I think still not available in Ubuntu repos.

Comment: Thunar is quite handy and seems to coexist well with other file browsers, so I think it may be worthwhile to install it for this purpose. But can you expand this answer with an explanation of *how* to do bulk renaming in Thunar?

Comment: @EliahKagan and it's lightweight too

Comment: Nicely done, now I can upvote (I've got a Xubuntu I can test it in too :) )